# Disable direct access by IP (nginx)

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have configured two servers domain and subdomain but also I'm trying to block access to site by IP of my server. Now if you go by IP address it just redirect to domain.

```
# app server configuration
server {

    root /var/www/html;
    server_name app.example.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://external_server_ip:8080; 
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    if ($host !~ ^(app.example.net)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }
    if ($http_id = '') {
        return 401;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.example.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.example.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    ~text/css                   30d;
    ~application/javascript     30d;
    ~image/                    30d;
}

# Default server configuration
server {

    root /var/www/html;
    server_name example.net www.example.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; 
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        limit_except GET HEAD POST { deny all; }
             
    }

    if ($http_host != $server_name) {
        return 444;
    }

    if ($host !~ ^(example.net|www.example.net)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }
    ## Block download agents ##
    if ($http_user_agent ~* LWP::Simple|BBBike|wget|zgrab|WebSucker01h4x.com|360Spider|404checker|404enemy|80legs|ADmantX|AIBOT|ALittle\ Client|ASPSeek|Go-Ahead-Got-It|GoZilla|Gotit|GrabNet|Grabber|Grafula|Niki-bot|Nikto|NimbleCrawler|Nimbostratus|Ninja|Nmap|Xaldon_WebSpider|Xenu|YoudaoBot|Zade|Zauba|Zermelo|Zeus|Zitebot|ZmEu|seocompany.store|seoscanners|seostar|serpstatbot|sexsearcher|sitechecker.pro|siteripz|sogouspider|sp_auditbot|spyfu|sysscan|tAkeOut|trendiction.com|trendiction.de|ubermetrics-technologies.com|voyagerx.com|webgains-bot|webmeup-crawler|webpros.com|webprosbot|x09Mozilla|x22Mozilla) {
        return 403;
    }
    ## Deny certain Referers ###
    if ( $http_referer ~* (seo|referrer|redirect|babes|click|girl|jewelry|love|organic|poker|porn|sex|teen|video|webcam) ) {
        return 403;
    }
    # deny access to .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    # Deny access to hidden files (beginning with a period)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    expires $expires;

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {

    if ($host = www.example.net) {
        return 301 https://example.net$request_uri;
    } 
    if ($host = example.net) {
        return 301 https://example.net$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name example.net www.example.net;
    return 301 https://example.net$request_uri;
    return 404; 

}
```

I tried to compare $host with domain and return 444, tried to create server block with server_name "" and _  but nothing helped. I also placed it in several places in code and nothing, same behavior.

I would be very appreciate for some help or advice what I'm doing wrong in code.

Comment: You have a naked `return 301 https://example.net$request_uri;` in the last server block. The `if...return 444` in the first block looks fine. The `if...return 444` in the second block will not work. `!=` is used to compare a variable with a string.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks a lot, you directed me and I made it work.